# Amazon DynamoDB mapping enums

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I need to map a User class for Amazon DynamoDB. One of the properties on the User object is AccountType (an enum). How do I handle this? Below is the enum and the code I have tried.

```
public enum AccountType {
    TYPE_A,
    TYPE_B
}
```

-

```
@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName="AccountType")   *<< THIS FAILS*
public AccountType getAccountType() {
    return accountType;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Question could be improved by specifying the error message or failure codition: Is the record not being persisted?  Does the error occur at build time? At run time? During a specific test?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The high-level API (the *Object Persistence model*) for [Amazon DynamoDB](http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/) provided by the [AWS SDK for Java](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforjava/) doesn't support `enum` yet, see [Supported Data Types](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/JavaSDKHighLevel.html#JavaSupportedTypeORMModel):

> Amazon DynamoDB supports the following primitive data types and
>   primitive wrapper classes.
>
> - String
> - Boolean, boolean
> - Byte, byte
> - Date (as ISO8601 millisecond-precision string, shifted to UTC)
> - Calendar (as ISO8601 millisecond-precision string, shifted to UTC)
> - Long, long
> - Integer, int
> - Double, double
> - Float, float
> - BigDecimal
> - BigInteger

However, *Amazon DynamoDB supports arbitrary data types* in principle, so you might be able to work around that limitation, see [Mapping Arbitrary Data with Amazon DynamoDB Using the AWS SDK for Java Object Persistence Model](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/JavaArbitraryDataMappingHLAPI.html) for details:

> In addition to the supported Java types [...],
>   you can use types in your application for which there is no direct
>   mapping to the Amazon DynamoDB types. To map these types, you must
>   provide an implementation that converts your complex type to an
>   instance of String and vice-versa and annotate the complex type
>   accessor method using the @DynamoDBMarshalling annotation type. [...]

Comment: This answer is no longer valid.

Answer (score 80):

The AWS SDK supports the special annotation [DynamoDBTypeConvertedEnum](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBTypeConvertedEnum.html) to convert an enum into a string.

```
@DynamoDBTypeConvertedEnum
@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName="AccountType")
public AccountType getAccountType() {
    return accountType;
}
```