# Set enum field to default value in case no value is passed

Tags: java, enums, default-value

I have a gender enum like this:

```
public enum GenderEnum {
    INVALID,
    MALE,
    FEMALE;

    public static GenderEnum from(String text) {
        if (text == null) {
            return INVALID;
        } else {
            return valueOf(text);
        }
    }
}
```

I have another class which uses a reference of `GenderEnum`. There could be instances when we won't get any value for gender, in such cases, the call fails with message `could not convert attribute`. How can I make it set to INVALID by default?

Example

```
 public class User {
 
     //.... other fields ....
     private GenderEnum gender; 
 }
```

Comment: some details of how this is being used in another class, like where/how the values are being get, would be helpful. The obvious way is setting an initial value `private GenderEnum gender = GenderEnum.INVALID`, but just a wild guess since missing any details

Comment: It's a field in another class, updated my question with an example.

Comment: I've tried that way too. It doesn't work.
There is a request object A, that contains another object ASmall where User is a field. 
This is the structure.

Comment: can you write the exact error message?

Comment: Found the issue, it was due to some other reason. Ref - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12589654/amazon-dynamodb-mapping-enums

Answer (score 1):

The method [valueOf(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String)) return Expection when argument is invalid :

- `IllegalArgumentException` if the specified enum type has no constant with the specified name, or the specified class object does not represent an enum type
- `NullPointerException` if enumType or name is null

You can write:

```java
public static GenderEnum from(String text) {
    GenderEnum gender;

    try {
        gender = valueOf(text);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException | NullPointerException e) {
        gender = INVALID;
    }
    
    return gender;
}
```

Or simplify:

```java
public static GenderEnum from(String text) {
    GenderEnum gender = INVALID;

    try {
        gender = valueOf(text);
    } catch (Exception ignore) { }
    
    return gender;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but this is still not working for me. Getting same issue.